# Getting product details from 'add to cart' into view basket

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to web development and I am trying to build a fashion ecommerce site for a project.

I would like a user to be able to chose a product e.g a dress which has associated details like product name, product price, image and size in a page called product.html. I have been able using a separate javascript, to ensure that when a user presses 'add to cart' that the details are logged.

However, how do I then transfer these details to a separate basket.html page and display them?

I'm struggling to understand if I need to use local storage and if so how do I show the details if I'm using a separate javascript file and a another html file.

Essentially, if a user picks a product, how do I get that specific product and details to appear in my separate basket page?

Apologies if this is badly worded or made little sense !

Thank you :)

Comment: are you comfortable using a server side database?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to this, depending on how your ecommerce site is built and what parts you have control over.

You could

1. Submit it to a server and have it respected in the response of the next page.
2. Hold it locally using webstorage (localStorage or sessionStorage). Keep in mind, that 3rd-party-scripts on your website will be able to read it, too!
3. Share it with a server by setting a cookie (can be read by 3rd-party-scripts). Keep in mind the limited size of a cookie.
4. Pass the information along as query parameters. This can have affects on SEO (duplicated content because similiar pages are indexed by a search engine).
5. Pass information along as hash parameter. Those aren't transmitted to a server, but can be read from JavaScript (yours and 3rd party). It was a hack applied in the early days of Single Page Applications.

Comment: Hey there, thanks so much for replying! I'm just struggling to pull the javascript into the correct html page. I went with the local storage as this is for a project so security isn't a huge deal, but when I say e.g:  cartRow.innerText = localStorage.getItem('storedprice')  it inserts it into the page it got it from (product page) not the basket page. Do you how i could go about fixing this? Thank you :)

Comment: I just tried on a live session and it worked:
`localStorage.setItem("storedprice", JSON.stringify({ my: "data" }))`, then a page change (with loading HTML from server, i.e. no SPA), then `console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storedprice")))`. I'd need more HTML / a minimal working example to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can build REST API which will be used to

- store item into cart (called when pressed Add to cart button)
- read items from cart (called on Basket page)

The API will persist it in some sort of DB and return when needed.

REST API should be secured (e.g. by OAuth2) so you can distinguish actions for individual users.